# Highcharts graph breaking line after rendering

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've a graph that is being rendered from some points I have in my database.

If I take all the points from the database and place them in the highcharts object, it sometimes "breakes" a random place on the graph and make a straight horisontal line.

Does anyone know any solution for this?

Here is a picture of the graph:
[image]

Comment: first thing that I would check is that your data is sorted by x value - that can cause problems of this nature.

Comment: So you mean if it isn't sorted from lowest to highest or highest to lowest?

Comment: the data must be sorted by x value, low to high

Comment: It's sorted from low to high :/

Comment: Can you a live example?

Comment: I can see it's because highcharts is giving 0.2 as x value - and Highcharts only accepts 0.20 for example. But I don't know how to fix this (error code 15). Any idea?

Comment: 0.2 is perfectly fine. In fact, 0.20 would be truncated to 0.2 even if you sent it that way. What error 15 says is exactly what I said -> your data needs to be in ascending x value order...